How do I style these images to scale within my website's header?
I have very little experience coding so any feedback is appreciated.I am trying to style 2 images (one jpg, one gif) using css so that they both appear above my navigation bar, inside the red container in the first screenshot. The end goal is to have a header/navigation bar that all scales as one (see fourth screenshot).
Let me know if you have any questions.
I have attempted to use rem/vh/vw instead of px/percentages, but the images did not scale then either.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaqueries.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="inner_header">
          <div class="icon_container"><img src="assets/icon1.jpg" alt="Icon"></div>
          <div class="title_container"><img src="assets/header.gif" alt=""></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation_bar">
      <nav id="desktop-nav">
        <div>
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#studio-work">studio work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#personal-work">personal work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


/* DESKTOP NAV */

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    display: block;
    background-color: gray;
}

.inner_header {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
}

.icon_container {   
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    /* vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%; */
}

.title_container {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: right;
}

nav, .nav-links {
    display: flex;
}

.navigation_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
}

nav {
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 4rem;
}

.nav-links {
    gap: 7rem;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

The website header is mapped out with grey and red container boxes. A basic navigation bar is below, with an empty red box above
The current state of my website's header with all layers turned on.
The ideal end result for my website's header: A logo, followed by an animated title card, and the navigation bar centred below both.

I would use display flex and have the images be seperated with one left aligned and one right aligned without the wrapping div like this:


/* DESKTOP NAV */

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    display: block;
    background-color: gray;
}

.inner_header {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
    justify-content: space-between;
  img {
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    
  }
}

nav, .nav-links {
    display: flex;
}

.navigation_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
}

nav {
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 4rem;
}

.nav-links {
    gap: 7rem;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}
 <div class="header">
      <div class="inner_header">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="Icon">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/900/200" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation_bar">
      <nav id="desktop-nav">
        <div>
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#studio-work">studio work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#personal-work">personal work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>



Im missing some of your css but this should do the trick.  specifically the css for inner_header and remove the img wrapping divs.

Thank you for the help! The code/explanation you gave got me the result I was looking for :)
